Raster calculator giving unexpectedly large and integer results
I am trying to divide one raster ("s05") by the other ("d_05") and the resulting raster ("SdivD") is giving me some suspicious values.
I am using ArcMap. The raster s05 values range from 0.0000206 to 0.440361, the raster d_05 values range from -0.0878448 to 2.0319. However, the resulting raster ranges from -39537 to 40542. I used the raster calculator tool with the math: "s_05.tif"/"d05.tif". All files are float 32bit.


I tried the same in QGIS and R but it is giving me the same result. I also tried converting the rasters into 64 bit but no luck. Can someone please explain how is this result possible? Am I doing something wrong? Can't really figure this one out. I was expecting to get much lower decimal values.

Look at the properties of the raster, what is your nodata value?
